# Indenting HTML elements, same line or nested element?

Tags: html, indentation

I was wondering if there is a standard or "correct" way to have content within an HTML element. I learned that content should be between the opening and closing tags and all on the same line (or rather, not nested), like such:

```
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<p>In tincidunt enim justo, sit amet consectetur odio dignissim nec.</p>
```

However this becomes a bit harder to read as the paragraphs get longer. Can you nest the element content like such?

```
<h2>
   Heading 1 and some additional text
</h2>
<p>
   In tincidunt enim justo, sit amet consectetur odio dignissim nec. Curabitur aliquet porttitor.
</p>
```

I feel like this becomes easier to read but I don't know if that goes against what's "right". Can you mix and match the two?

Below is a photo that shows a more real life example between the two different formatting types, and I think this helps to show the readability between the two styles.

Also, this is my first Stack Overflow post! This community is great and has helped me out so much. I'm excited to start asking questions and becoming a more active member! Thanks all.

Image with different paragraph styles:

[image: Image with different paragraph styles]

Comment: There is no correct way. It's all up to you and the team you work with (if any).

Comment: Note that this question is considered "primarily opinion-based", and as such should be closed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How is this opinion? he asked _Can you mix and match the two?_ that is not an opinion question. Mixing and matching the two has no effect on the HTML.

Comment: "I was wondering if there is a standard or "correct" way to have content within an HTML element. " "I feel like this becomes easier to read but I don't know if that goes against what's "right"."

Comment: Consistency is key.  If you're working in a company or team, stick to any given style guides. If not, stick with what works for you. My rule of thumb is if the opening and closing tags can be visible on one line, then so be it. Just make sure your code is readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in HTML it doesn't matter where you have line breaks. You could put all your code on one line if you wanted to.

Comment: So all of the line breaks and nesting is just for readability then, correct?

Comment: @KenZimny Yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a very forgiving language in this sense. But it is good practice to keep it as  readable as possible. Not only while working in a team but also for yourself if you ever have to revisit your code.

Most code editors have auto formatting options to make it easier keeping your code nice and neat.